# Jmeter big JTL Report File Thread based Reporting

Tags: command-line, jmeter, reporting, bigdata

I’m currently load testing an web based application with a couple of pc’s(4 older pc’s) each with about 200 threads over 6h. As recommended everywhere on the web, I’ve used best practice settings for the saveservice and JTL output.

The issue here is the file size I’m getting after 6h run. The result JTL is about 1.2GB and about 2 million lines which can’t be opened or edited that easy with windows tools. The point is I need to report latency based for each thread count (e.g. 5, 50,100,200 Threads). If I’m using one large file its close to be impossible with windows tools to extract and create a new JTL with the thread count I want to report on and if I’m setting up the command line to run a batch of 5 Jmeter runs for each thread count a different JTL it’s still too big to be opened. I’m not that experienced in programming ore scripting and need a solution for thread based reporting from a big JTL file.

Does anyone have a suggestion to handle that?

Btw. I've read about Blazemeter and Loadsophia and co but they are not an suitable solution for me.

```
4PC - need to run CL
2GHz 2 Cores, <2GB Ram, Win7


Sample batch I’ve used
call ..\jmeter -n -t versuch.jmx -l ${__time("yyMMddHHmmss")}_Threads-${__P(threads)}.jtl -Jthreads=5 -Jrampup=0 -Jloopcount=3000
call ..\jmeter -n -t versuch.jmx -l ${__time("yyMMddHHmmss")}_Threads-${__P(threads)}.jtl -Jthreads=50 -Jrampup=0 -Jloopcount=3000
call ..\jmeter -n -t versuch.jmx -l ${__time("yyMMddHHmmss")}_Threads-${__P(threads)}.jtl -Jthreads=100 -Jrampup=0 -Jloopcount=3000


jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a JMeter reporting backend

- handles huge JTL (multiple GBs)
- creates an extended JMeter HTML report
- parses CSV & XML JMeter report files

See https://github.com/sgoeschl/jmeter-sla-report

Cheers,

Siegfried Goeschl

Comment: Does this also generate the graphs?